# React Native: Using JS Stylesheet vs CSS/SCSS for styles

Tags: css, react-native, sass, react-native-stylesheet

I've been told that using CSS/SCSS to define styles in React Native is a better practice than just using the native StyleSheet from 'react-native'.

I've been looking around a lot and can't find a single reason to agree on that, rather than the fact that if you already have css styles, it's easier to import them into React Native, than "converting" them.

But I don't see any reason to start a brand new React Native application with CSS/SCSS.

Am I missing something? Is it a matter of taste?
Is it even possible to use only CSS/SCSS on React Native?

Comment: Everyone has an opinion on styling in RN. Just use whatever you feel is most maintainable. If you want CSS, styled-components are the standard approach, but using a styled component for EVERY SINGLE element that needs a rule applied to it will add a large amount of boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

It is matter of taste. In regular web development people are to use CSS. React-native is sense is web development. I personally don't see any sense in installing a package that would support css. Anyway, you get the same results when you css or StyleSheet